# How to handle admin-editable, freeform text in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text, rubygems, markdown

I'm trying to add a *guidelines doc* type page to my Rails app (e.g. like if Stack Overflow wanted [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be editable at anytime by admins or moderators). I don't want to hardcode it in HTML, because editing it would require a full deploy. This would be a living document that admins in the system could add to and edit at any time.

In terms of letting admins edit the text in a friendly, non-technical way, I'll probably just make this text markdown.

**My question:** Is there a ruby gem that handles this? This might not be the last time I'll need editable living documents in the app. In fact, the /about page might be a good candidate for this as well. Of course I could just create a model/table with text fields, but I could have sworn I came across one or more gems that took care of this elegantly. Can't seem to recall what they were at all...

Thanks!

Comment: "Is there a ruby gem that handles this?" It's off-topic on Stack Overflow to ask for recommendations. Instead, you need to show what you've tried and describe why it didn't work.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for the feedback, but I'm unclear on why this is off-topic. I need to show why *what* didn't work?

Comment: See [#4 on the "Help Center > Asking"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right you need to keep some pages in Markdown format for easy editing.

To do this you can use [kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/). It is the Markdown engine that can convert your .md-files to .html. First add to your Gemfile the following line:

```
gem 'kramdown', '~> 1.4.1'
```

In your controller:

```
require 'kramdown'

#...

def show
  text =  File.read('app/assets/readme.md')
  @html = Kramdown::Document.new(template).to_html
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= @html.html_safe %>
```

The next question is to cache your page so rendering won't occure every time the user requests the page.

Comment: thanks for the tip on kramdown. I guess my question was more on how to store these text blobs in the database, so that a deploy isn't needed each time. As in, should I just make a EditableText model with a "content" field for every text blob an admin would need to edit?

Comment: You can load Markdown to the text variable from different sources including database. Admin edits file in web interface or in text editor on server?

Comment: Web interface, within the Rails app.

Comment: Then it is some kind of CMS, I think